# Generate XML-Report for xUnit using Visual Studio Runner

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, xunit

I just setup a new project (.net 4.6.2) using xUnit Tests. In order to get unit-testing in VSTS I added the visual-studio runner to the project (using nuget).

Now I'm wondering: how do I get XML-Reports of my testruns, so I can publish those results in VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Visual Studio Test task** to run XUnit and it can publish the test result to VSTS.

Regarding Core xUnit test, you can generate the trx test result by specifying `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --logger "trx"` arguments in **.Net Core Test** task and add **Publish Test Results task** to publish test result (Choose `VSTest` in Test result format)

Comment: One thing I was missing: I didn't see any tests in the result in the build-summary in VSTS - until I realized, that only *failed* test are being shown by default. So I switched to display *all* tests - and I got my list of succeeded tests :)

Answer (score 6):

Xunit logger can generate xml reports in the xunit v2 format (https://xunit.github.io/docs/format-xml-v2.html).

1. Add a reference to the [Xunit Logger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitXml.TestLogger/2.0.0) nuget package in test project
2. Use the following command line in tests
   dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:xunit
3. Test results are generated in the TestResults directory relative to the test.csproj
   A path for the report file can be specified as follows:
   dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:xunit;LogFilePath=loggerFile.xml
   loggerFile.xml will be generated in the same directory as test.csproj.

Comment: I am not working on a dotnet core project,  but a dotnet framework project. Thus I don't have dotnet.exe to execute my tests.

Comment: I get "Could not find a test logger with URI or FriendlyName xunit"